Error: NG0400: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first
I'm using angular/element to create custom web element with angular14.2.0 in Remote application. It is working in remote angular application but when I am trying to use this in Shell application with micro-frontend .It is giving error ' A platform with a different configuration has been created'. I used WrapperComponent

  constructor() { }

  
  elm = inject(ElementRef);

  @Input() config = initWrapperConfig;

  async ngOnInit() {
    debugger

    console.log("In WrapperComponent................")
    const { exposedModule, remoteName, elementName } = this.config;

    await loadRemoteModule({remoteName:'remote', exposedModule:'./web-components', remoteEntry: "http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js"});
    const root = document.createElement('mfe2-root');
    this.elm.nativeElement.appendChild(root);
    console.log("root===",root)
  }
}


export interface WrapperConfig {
    remoteName: string;
    exposedModule: string;
    elementName: string;
}

export const initWrapperConfig: WrapperConfig = {
    remoteName: '',
    exposedModule: '',
    elementName: '',
}````


